# How are the packet boundaries in the Source engine DEM format determined?

Tags: source-engine, game-recording

I'm trying to write a program that reads [Source DEM files](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/DEM_Format), and about all I can at this point is the header which is a magic string, few `int`s and `float`s and 280-long strings.

The last field in the header is an `int` which specifies the length of the "sign on" data in bytes, but after reading that much forward into the file then attempting to read a new `int` for another packet of data, I get garbage values (0's or negative values) after 2-3 packets (I expect a few thousand).

Basically I'm interpreting the documentation as so:

- Header Data (less sign-on length)
- Sign-on length (`int`, "Length of the signon data (Init for first frame)")
- Sign-on packet (of above specified length)
- Next packet length (`int`)
- Next packet data (length above)
- ...repeat to EOF.

If I consume another 4-bytes between the "sign-on length" and packet itself (it's a bit unclear if the last field in the header is actually part of the header or just the start of the first packet), I also get garbage.

All this is before even trying to parse the contents of the packet data, I'm currently just trying to jump through the recording and chop it up in to the frame packets.

Comment: While I think this falls into the category of "modding" and is thus technically on-topic here, you should be aware that these sorts of questions tend to get very few answers and you may want to make sure you are also looking for information elsewhere.

Comment: @Josh, this already is "elsewhere" #3.

Comment: At this point, you might want to try stepping through the engine's demo creation code via breakpoint injection, if possible. Otherwise, I'd look through the code provided with the Source SDK to see if the demo code is in there. You might have to get more creative than that with reverse engineering... please publish your work if you do!

Comment: @NickT Bummer. Well, good luck. :|

Comment: @shotgun is the source to Source open?  I don't have the engine to develop with but am trying to make an independent tool